# Get records from one table excluding records from another

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select records from the `master table` where they match records in the `new table`, but excluding records where the `new table` matches the `old table`. The `urn` field is a common denominator between them all.

My query is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `master`
JOIN `new` ON `master`.`urn` = `new`.`urn`
LEFT JOIN `old` ON `old`.`urn` = `new`.`urn`
```

I'm sure this should work, but it doesn't return the correct amount of results.

Any suggestions very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

For such a query, I would think `exists` and not `exists`:

```
select m.*
from master m
where exists (select 1 from new n where n.urn = m.urn) and
      not exists (select 1 from old o where o.urn = m.urn);
```

I prefer `exists` to an explicit `join` because there is no danger that duplicates in `new` will result in duplicates in the result set.  I also find that it more closely represents the purpose of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `WHERE` condition probably like

```
SELECT *
FROM `master`
JOIN `new` ON `master`.`urn` = `new`.`urn`
LEFT JOIN `old` ON `old`.`urn` = `new`.`urn`
WHERE `old`.`urn` IS NULL;
```